# Set of Monotonic functions , power

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to determine whether the set of monotonic functions defined on $[0,1]$ has the cardinality of continuum or not. I want to use the fact that monotonic functions have at most countable discontinuities but I am not sure if I am on the right track or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: consider the following 2 facts:

1. the family of functions $\{y=ax: a\in \mathbb{R}\}$ already has the cardinality of the continuum,
2. the cardinality of family of continuous functions is at most the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ (since the value at rational points uniquely identify a function)...

Comment: The second part is not exactly the right hint here. The OP already knows that these functions can be discontinuous.

Comment: I think for each continuous monotone function you can build at most $|\mathbb{R}|$ monotone functions (choose discontinuity points, then choose the "magnitude" of each discontinuity). Then one has to prove that you build all monotone functions in this way...

Comment: Where did that $\aleph_1$ come from?

Comment: sorry, edited to $|\mathbb{R}|$.